# Add mouse hover containing specific data to d3.js tree map

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I put together the following treemap using d3.js. It's the top 20 states in terms of voter turnout. [Link](https://oihamza.github.io/Interactive-Data-Vis-Fall2020/Project%201/)

I'm unsure how to add the 'values' into the hover. Ideally, it should show the unique value for each state. I'm able to do it for one (California in the example), but I'm not sure how to make it flexible so that it generates other values for different states.

```js
let margin = {
    top: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0
  },
  width = 1100 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 900 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
let svg = d3
  .select('#treemap')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');
// Read data
d3.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oihamza/Interactive-Data-Vis-Fall2020/master/Project%201/stateVoterTurnout.csv', function(data) {
  // stratify the data: reformatting for d3.js
  var root = d3
    .stratify()
    .id(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    }) // Name of the entity (column name is name in csv)
    .parentId(function(d) {
      return d.parent;
    })(
      // Name of the parent (column name is parent in csv)
      data
    );

  // data is an object
  console.log(data);

  let values = data[1].value;

  let tooltip = d3
    .select('body')
    .append('div')
    .style('position', 'absolute')
    .style('z-index', '10')
    .style('visibility', 'hidden')
    .style('background-color', 'white')
    .style('border', 'solid')
    .style('border-width', '2px')
    .style('border-radius', '5px')
    .style('padding', '5px')
    .text(`${values} voters`);

  root.sum(function(d) {
    return +d.value;
  }); // Compute the numeric value for each entity

  // Then d3.treemap computes the position of each element of the hierarchy
  // The coordinates are added to the root object above
  d3.treemap().size([width, height]).padding(3)(root);

  console.log(root.leaves());
  // use this information to add rectangles:

  svg
    .selectAll('rect')
    .data(root.leaves())
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('x', function(d) {
      return d.x0;
    })
    .attr('y', function(d) {
      return d.y0;
    })
    .attr('width', function(d) {
      return d.x1 - d.x0;
    })
    .attr('height', function(d) {
      return d.y1 - d.y0;
    })
    .style('stroke', 'black')
    .style('fill', '#945f04')
    .on('mouseover', function() {
      return tooltip.style('visibility', 'visible');
    })
    .on('mousemove', function() {
      return tooltip
        .style('top', d3.event.pageY - 10 + 'px')
        .style('left', d3.event.pageX + 10 + 'px');
    })
    .on('mouseout', function() {
      return tooltip.style('visibility', 'hidden');
    });

  // and to add the text labels

  svg
    .selectAll('text')
    .data(root.leaves())
    .enter()
    .append('text')
    .attr('x', function(d) {
      return d.x0 + 10;
    }) // +10 to adjust position (more right)
    .attr('y', function(d) {
      return d.y0 + 20;
    }) // +20 to adjust position (lower)
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.data.name;
    })
    .attr('font-size', '15px')
    .attr('fill', 'white');
});
```

```css
body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif
}

.styling {
  transform-origin: center center;
  align-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  /* border-bottom: 1px dotted black; */
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 180px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat">
<span class="styling"><div id="treemap"></div></span>

<!-- Loading this version of d3 -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `mouseover` or `mousemove` the rectangle, you can find it's assigned datum with the first argument (often called `d`) - just like you do when you set attributes with `.attr()` or styles with `.style()`.

You can set the `.text()` of the tooltip dynamically, using this `d`:

```js
let margin = {
    top: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0
  },
  width = 1100 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 900 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
let svg = d3
  .select('#treemap')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');
// Read data
d3.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oihamza/Interactive-Data-Vis-Fall2020/master/Project%201/stateVoterTurnout.csv', function(data) {
  // stratify the data: reformatting for d3.js
  var root = d3
    .stratify()
    .id(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    }) // Name of the entity (column name is name in csv)
    .parentId(function(d) {
      return d.parent;
    })(
      // Name of the parent (column name is parent in csv)
      data
    );

  let tooltip = d3
    .select('body')
    .append('div')
    .style('position', 'absolute')
    .style('z-index', '10')
    .style('visibility', 'hidden')
    .style('background-color', 'white')
    .style('border', 'solid')
    .style('border-width', '2px')
    .style('border-radius', '5px')
    .style('padding', '5px');

  root.sum(function(d) {
    return +d.value;
  }); // Compute the numeric value for each entity

  // Then d3.treemap computes the position of each element of the hierarchy
  // The coordinates are added to the root object above
  d3.treemap().size([width, height]).padding(3)(root);
  // use this information to add rectangles:

  svg
    .selectAll('rect')
    .data(root.leaves())
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('x', function(d) {
      return d.x0;
    })
    .attr('y', function(d) {
      return d.y0;
    })
    .attr('width', function(d) {
      return d.x1 - d.x0;
    })
    .attr('height', function(d) {
      return d.y1 - d.y0;
    })
    .style('stroke', 'black')
    .style('fill', '#945f04')
    .on('mouseover', function() {
      tooltip.style('visibility', 'visible');
    })
    .on('mousemove', function(d) {
      tooltip
        .style('top', d3.event.pageY - 10 + 'px')
        .style('left', d3.event.pageX + 10 + 'px')
        .text(`${d.data.value} voters`);
    })
    .on('mouseout', function() {
      tooltip.style('visibility', 'hidden');
    });

  // and to add the text labels

  svg
    .selectAll('text')
    .data(root.leaves())
    .enter()
    .append('text')
    .attr('x', function(d) {
      return d.x0 + 10;
    }) // +10 to adjust position (more right)
    .attr('y', function(d) {
      return d.y0 + 20;
    }) // +20 to adjust position (lower)
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.data.name;
    })
    .attr('font-size', '15px')
    .attr('fill', 'white');
});
```

```css
body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif
}

.styling {
  transform-origin: center center;
  align-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  /* border-bottom: 1px dotted black; */
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 180px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat">
<span class="styling"><div id="treemap"></div></span>

<!-- Loading this version of d3 -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```

It's not necessary to return anything inside these `.on()` functions.

Comment: It'd be slightly more optimal to set the text on mouseover (happens once per data section and remains the same) and on mousemove only update the position.

Comment: @kano you're right! On SO I generally prefer simplicity over optimality though, it makes it easier to explain things